# Neo4j Graph Algorithms no procedure with the name algo.nodeSimilarity

Tags: neo4j

I wanted to test some graph algorithms, [node similarity](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/algorithms/node-similarity/) in particular. So I've setup a docker container using `neo4j:3.5` (which is `v3.5.14` at the moment) official [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/neo4j). Additionally I've downloaded APOC [v3.5.0.7](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/releases/download/3.5.0.7/apoc-3.5.0.7-all.jar) and Graph Algorithms [v3.5.4.0](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-graph-algorithms/releases/download/3.5.4.0/graph-algorithms-algo-3.5.4.0.jar) and added this line to the config:

`dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=algo.*`

Unfortunately function `algo.nodeSimilarity` seems not to be present in the registered functions:

```
CALL algo.nodeSimilarity('Node', 'LABEL', {})
YIELD nodesCompared, relationships, write, writeRelationshipType, writeProperty
```

yields

> There is no procedure with the name `algo.nodeSimilarity` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed.

Also `call dbms.procedures` nor `call algo.list()` does not show `nodeSimilarity`. **The other functions** from APOC (e.g. `pageRank`) and Graph Algorithms (e.g. `louvain`) **are installed and work as expected**.

As I can see in the docs, the `algo.nodeSimilarity` should be present since `v3.5`. So I'm pretty much confused with this error. Would this be more suitable question for the Github Issues page on  Graph Algorithms plugin repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Github repo for the Graph Algorithms plugin doesn't seem to actually be up to date - the latest version of the plugin is [3.5.14](https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/com.neo4j.graphalgorithms.dist/neo4j-graph-algorithms-3.5.14.0-standalone.zip), available from the [download centre](https://neo4j.com/download-center/) which definitely contains the `algo.nodeSimilarity` algorithm. There are other versions available - [this JSON file](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-graph-algorithms/blob/master/versions.json) contains all the variants which isn't super discoverable.

The docs are a bit odd in that they claim everything is in v3.5, but don't say exactly which revision of 3.5 they appeared in. I can't tell when `algo.nodeSimilarity` appeared, but I'm using 3.5.13 in my 3.5.13 database and it's present there at least.

It doesn't appear that the Graph Algorithms library uses any form of semantic versioning, and I have yet to find a source for the historic release notes version-by-version.